# How do you automatically focus a textbox when a page loads?

Tags: html, css, text

I am building a search engine. How can I have the input tag (`type="text"`) be focused when the page loads so people can start searching straight away without having to click on it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, we expect at least some research before asking a question. There is at least one question on this site that answers exactly this and numerous results on any given search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `autofocus` attribute, which does exactly that.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and .focus() method.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#search_input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_input">
```